Problem installing `apache-flink:1.19.0` using python docker 3.9 - 3.12
I am having trouble installing PyFlink/apache-flink 1.19.0 using python docker 3.9 - 3.12 following the official tutorial.
It seems that the error is about a path that return NoneType, but I am not sure how to fix it.
I did not post python:3.12 as the error is the same as others.
Can you please help me on this?
Thank you very much.
Python 3.9
docker run - it python:3.9 python - m pip install apache-flink
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rdoi1tww/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rdoi1tww/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rdoi1tww/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-rdoi1tww/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 169, in <module>
          include_dirs=get_java_include() + ['src/main/c/pemja/core/include'],
        File "setup.py", line 111, in get_java_include
          inc = os.path.join(get_java_home(), inc_name)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
          a = os.fspath(a)
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Python 3.10
docker run - it python:3.10 python - m pip install apache-flink
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ptcni4h1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ptcni4h1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ptcni4h1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ptcni4h1/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 169, in <module>
          include_dirs=get_java_include() + ['src/main/c/pemja/core/include'],
        File "setup.py", line 111, in get_java_include
          inc = os.path.join(get_java_home(), inc_name)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
          a = os.fspath(a)
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Python 3.11
docker run - it python:3.11 python - m pip install apache-flink
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jpt4cjc2/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jpt4cjc2/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jpt4cjc2/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-jpt4cjc2/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 169, in <module>
          include_dirs=get_java_include() + ['src/main/c/pemja/core/include'],
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "setup.py", line 111, in get_java_include
          inc = os.path.join(get_java_home(), inc_name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen posixpath>", line 76, in join
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

UPDATE 15/4/2024
It works in Windows.  But it does not work in Mac when using this command:  Is it a permission problem?
docker run -it python:3.11 pip install apache-flink
My Mac Config:

M1 Max
Sonoma 14.4.1

Message below:
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r8xb1epe/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r8xb1epe/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r8xb1epe/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r8xb1epe/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 169, in <module>
          include_dirs=get_java_include() + ['src/main/c/pemja/core/include'],
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "setup.py", line 111, in get_java_include
          inc = os.path.join(get_java_home(), inc_name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen posixpath>", line 76, in join
      TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I'm not sure, when I run docker run -it --rm python:3.9 python -m pip install apache-flink I successfully install the module. Try to remove the spaces between - i and - m

Are you tied to using flink?

For those who are having this problem like me, who are trying to install apache-flink in Macbook M1 via docker, I found the answer.
The root cause: pemja requires JAVA_HOME to be set
So all you need to do is to install JAVA jdk (not jre) first:

I am using openjdk 17.  That is the only openJDK I found in Python:3.11 image.

To install, run apt install -y openjdk-17-jdk


Set JAVA_HOME variable by: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-arm64.

This is the location I found, your's may be different.  Look it up when necessary.


Install pemja: pip install pemja.
If the above success, run pip install apache-flink

Then you should be able to install apache-flink client successfully.
Then last step is to commit this image and create your own docker image:

docker commit -m "fix apche-flink install issue" <your container name> <your_docker_image_name>:<your_docker_image_tag>

Hope it helps someone.

These commands should work:
docker run -it python:3.9 pip install apache-flink
docker run -it python:3.10 pip install apache-flink
docker run -it python:3.11 pip install apache-flink

The apache-flink package will be installed onto the running container in all cases. However, immediately after the package is installed the container will terminate, so it's not terribly useful.
What would make more sense would be to create a new image with the package installed.
 Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11

RUN pip install apache-flink==1.19.0

The build and run.
docker build -t python-flink .
docker run -it python-flink

In the running you container you will be able to import pyflink.


I did not post python:3.12 as the error is the same as others.

Are you sure? I actually get a different error with Python 3.12 that looks like a version compatibility issue with the apache-flink package.

Yes it works for Python:3.11.  For Python3.12, I am sure I got the same error as before (I'm using mac).  Today when I am using windows I got a different one: AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?.  But anyway, Thank you for your help.

Yes, that's the same error that I got with Python 3.12. I think that there must be a compatibility issue for the present version of apache-flink and Python 3.12.

It is weird: I got the same error if I am using Mac.  Updated the question

Okay, so do you need Python 3.12 or will 3.11 do? If so then I think that the problem is solved.

I need 3.11, and I am using Mac with Docker, yet it only works for windows, I hope you can help.

This works on Linux and presumably Mac too: docker run -it python:3.11 pip install apache-flink. I'm not clear on what the issue is when you use that. Above you commented "Yes it works for Python:3.11".
